# How to determine whether a solution of a transport PDE is classical?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, transport-equation

I have to determine whether the solution of:$$u_y+2u_x=0 , x>0,y>0 ,\quad u(x,0)=x ,x\geq 0 ,\quad u(0,y)=y ,y\geq0$$ is a classical solution.

I found that the solution is:$$u(x,y)=\frac{-x+2y}{2} , \quad if \quad 0<x<2y$$
$$u(x,y)=x-2y , \quad if \quad x>2y$$

My solution is continous when $x=2y$ but how to show if it is differentiable(once) both for $u_x, u_y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $u$ can be rewritten

\begin{align} u(x,y) &= U(x-2y),\\ U(z) &= \begin{cases}-z/2  & z<0 \\ z & z>0\end{cases}
\\
&=\frac{|z|}2+ \frac12\begin{cases}0  & z<0 \\ z & z>0\end{cases}
\\
&=\frac{|z|}2 + \frac{z+|z|}4 = \frac34|z| + \frac z4.
\end{align}
Because
$$ |x-2y|$$
is not differentiable, it follows that $u$ is not either.

Comment: could you tell me how can i prove that |x-2y| is not differentiable because i am not sure how to prove it?

Comment: @george_ioanidis can you prove that $|x|$ is not differentiable? What about $|x+1|$?

Comment: Ok,I understand.